# How to align last data point value in a tag on Y Axis in line chart of HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

As you can see, it's printed the endpoint value of the chart as a colorful tag like the following image:

[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVVqN.png)

The problem is that the labels overlap each other, I want to fix them in the same position and not move even if I zoom. I want the labels to be one below the other.

The following code is how I create those labels (I'm using react btw):
events:

```js
{
          render() {
            try {
              const chart = this;
              if (chart.renderTo && chart.series.length > 0) {
                if (chart.lastLabels && chart.lastLabels.length > 0) {
                  chart.lastLabels.forEach(label => label.destroy());
                }
                chart.lastLabels = [];
                chart.series.forEach((series, seriesIndex) => {
                  if (series.visible) {
                    const points = series.points;
                    const lastPoint = points[points.length - 1];
                    const x = lastPoint.plotX + chart.plotLeft;
                    const y = lastPoint.plotY + chart.plotTop;
                    console.log(`Value de Y para ${series.name}:`, y);


                    const seriesColor = series.color;
                    console.log('datos', chartData);
                    const label = chart.renderer.label(`${series.name}: ${Number(lastPoint.y).toFixed(2)}`, x + 20, y - 12, 'callout', x, y)
                      .css({
                        color: seriesColor,
                        'font-size': '14px',
                      })
                      .attr({
                        fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
                        padding: 8,
                        r: 5,
                        zIndex: 6
                      });
                    if (!isMobile) {
                      label.add();
                      chart.lastLabels.push(label);
                    }
                  }
                });
                if (!isMobile) {
                  chart.series.forEach((series) => {
                    if (series.visible) {
                      const points = series.points;
                      const lastPoint = points[points.length - 1];
                      const x = lastPoint.plotX + chart.plotLeft;
                      const y = chart.plotHeight + chart.plotTop + 10;
                      const seriesColor = series.color;
                      const lastDate = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y', lastPoint.x);
                      const label = chart.renderer.label(lastDate, x, y, 'callout', 0, 0)
                        .css({
                          color: seriesColor // Color de la serie para cada label
                        })
                        .attr({
                          fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
                          padding: 8,
                          r: 5,
                          zIndex: 6
                        }).add();
                      chart.lastLabels.push(label);
                    }
                  });
                }
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          }
        },
      },
```

Thank you

Comment: could you please add code pen, will be better to help you with live code